# Universal USB Installer does not recognize the iso file

Tags: usb, system-installation

I downloaded Ubuntu Desktop 12.04 LTS 32-bit.
Used the Universal USB Installer, but it wouldnt recognize the file. 
It was a clean download and I'm quite sure that its not damaged.
Any suggestion or any other software you'd recommend?

Comment: Its not recognizing the ISO?  What OS are using to create the USB?

Comment: Try [Unetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/) , also verify the md5sum of ISO before using using it.

Comment: Did you download the [latest version of *Universal USB installer*](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/). Because if you have an older version, it will not recognize the newer iso.

Comment: @tijybba I recommend posting that as an answer.

Answer (score 4):

Try [Unetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/) ,select the appropriate installer  file based on your Current OS and also verify the **md5sum** of ISO before using it.

A suggestion , see screenshot

[image]

1. Don't select the first option `Distribution` , because it does not lists the current   **Ubuntu Precise Pangolin 12.04** edition. So rather ,
2. Select the `Diskimage` option , then Browse to the location of the Ubuntu ISO image from the `....`  button.
3. **IMPORTANT** option , select the `Type` and `Drive` Option Very Carefully to avoid data loss . If it is Usb Drive , most probably will be **sdbX** , **sdcX**, do a cross check and Proceed with `OK` option.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem in my windows 7. It doesn't recognize not only ubuntu iso but also all other ISO I have.

I would recomend, LILI.

[From here](http://www.linuxliveusb.com/en/download) you can get it.

Answer (score 0):

The utility looks for a certain file name pattern, not just the extension. So, ensure you are selecting the correct OS type - Desktop or Server.

If you select 'Ubuntu' it will look for the 'Desktop' iso and ignore all others. If you select Ubuntu Server it will look for the Server iso and ignore all others.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get around this problem with Universal USB Installer by selecting "Try Unlisted Linux" as the distro. It also would not display my USB drive so I had to select "show all drives". After that I got the "create" button to appear.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem. Be sure that the iso's name  matches exactly the name that appears in Step 2. If they don't match you can solve it renaming the iso file. It worked for me.

[image]

Answer (score -2):

The name is probably ubuntu-12.04.4-Alternate-i386, so change alternate to Desktop, the application tells you that is the way it determine it.

Comment: The OP says they downloaded an Ubuntu Desktop image. ("*I downloaded Ubuntu Desktop 12.04 LTS 32-bit.*") If that's the case, why would the iso file be named "alternate" instead of "desktop"?